# What is the unit of the Threshold value in Cloud Monitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am trying to wrap my head around Threshold value in the context of creating an alerting policy for an external HTTP load balancer:

Resource type: `https_lb_rule`
Metric: `https/request_count`

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui#default) say the following:

> Enter when the value of a metric violates the threshold by using the Threshold position and Threshold value fields. For example, if you set these values to Above threshold and 0.3, then any measurement higher than 0.3 violates the threshold.

Now what does the value `0.3` indicate? Is there any unit and how do I relate to it in the context of the `https/request_count` metric for `https_lb_rule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threshold value Reflects the minimum performance required to achieve the required operational effect. A threshold is an amount, level, or limit on a scale. When the threshold is reached, something else happens or changes.threshold means point or level where the alert needs to trigger at some specified point

As per your concerns  Google Cloud HTTP/S Load Balancing Rule - Request count has a numeric value for threshold it means it will count the requests received for the load balancer.

If you give a threshold value of 10 then when the count of the requests received  is above 10 then alert will trigger.You will be getting alerts frequently after crossing the given value. There is an option in advanced options as  restart count as shown in below image it will help you to reduce the notifications. If the  Restart window value is 1hr, then if the count is greater than the threshold for 1h(i.e, >10), then alert policy will  open an incident and send notification to you.